# wxPython, key events not showing up on MacOS and Linux

Tags: python, wxpython

In my project, I've hand-rolled a tiny dialog box that can be used to pick a key and/or mouse combination, "S" or "CTRL-SHIFT-C" or something.  I had it working fine in Linux and Windows, but when I went to check it on the Mac, the dialog box would only respond to mouse events.

I boiled it down to a ~30-line minimal example, which actually made it be broken in the same way, mouse events but no keyboard, on Linux.  On Windows my minimal code works as expected.

I've looked at the demo code, and I feel like I'm doing pretty precisely the things they're doing, so I'm stumped, most especially by the simple code being broken on Linux.  Is there some magic or secret to making key events work reliably and cross-platform?

```
import wx

class Main(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS|wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL);
    desc = wx.StaticText( self, -1, "I receive mouse events but not kbd events")
    sizer.Add( desc, 1, wx.ALL, 25);

    for i in [self, desc]:
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR_HOOK       , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_CHAR            , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN        , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_UP          , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )

        i.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN       , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_MIDDLE_DOWN     , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_RIGHT_DOWN      , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_AUX1_DOWN , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )
        i.Bind(wx.EVT_MOUSE_AUX2_DOWN , self.OnKeyOrMouseEvt )

    self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer);

def OnKeyOrMouseEvt(self, event):
    print(f"I have received an event: {event}")
    event.Skip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    main = Main(None)
    main.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm on Mac and I've learned something from your question too.  As you had it, you are correct, it didn't work properly. So finding a working answer solved it for us both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran this on OSX 11.4. Works fine with mouse and key events. The imporant part on OSX (and I suspect Linux as it is more similar to OSX than Windows) is that the parent panel is getting the focus and the events. Also, `StaticText` can't get focus.

Here's the working code:

```
import wx


class Main(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.WANTS_CHARS|wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)

        panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.on_mouse_key_event)
        panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.on_mouse_key_event)

    def on_mouse_key_event(self, event):
        print(f'{event}')

# Run the program
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    main = Main(None)
    main.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Aha that is fascinating!  Adding the one line "panel = wx.Panel(self. -1)" without any further reference to the panel anywhere made it work.  Very weird but I can do that.  Thanks for the pointer!  Oh, yeah and I had the StaticText getting Bind() because on one of the platforms, can't recall now, not doing that would miss any mouse events that happened on top of the text.  Write once, debug everywhere.

Comment: Yeah, just keep in mind where the focus is, and some things can't get focus, so you have to wrap them in things that can get focus.

Comment: So yeah just to follow up, putting that single line in the dialog box out in my full codebase made it pick up the keys just fine on Mac.  So there apparently needs to be a wx.Panel in the mix somewhere, even if it's unused, in order to get the key events.  Thanks again.

Comment: This was half the solution for me. However, my main Frame is completely filled with Panels containing UI components. To ensure the that the "dummy" panel got focus, I had to add it after all the real UI components and make it the same size as the main Frame.